# The difference of two numbers with the same digits

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have no idea how to reach this algebraically.

I have tried numerous approaches with no avail.

$x,y,z \in \{1,2,\ldots 9\}$ such that $z<y<x.$ Let $K$ be the largest three digit number that has digits $x,y,z$, and $L$ be the smallest three digit number that has the same digits. Prove algebraically that $K-L$ is a multiple of $99$.

Comment: Well, are $x,y,z$ digits?  That is to say, between $1$ and $9$, inclusive?  Assuming they are, then Hint:  $K=100x+10y+z$.  What is $L$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Note that the larger number is

$100\cdot x+10\cdot y +z$

can you write the smallest? and the difference?

Answer (score 0):

$K = 100x+10y+z,$ and $L = 100z + 10y + x,$ hence $$K-L = 99x-99z = 99(x-z).$$ Now, since $x>z$ and $x,z \in \{1,2,\ldots,9\}$ we have, $$(K-L)/99 = x-z \in \{1,2,\ldots,8\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$100x+10y+z$ is the greatest 3 digit no. which can be formed by given digits.
And $100z+10y+x$ is the smallest 3 digit no.
Difference = $(100x+10y+z)-(100z+10y+x)=99(x-z)=99k$  where k is positive integer.

Hence Proved!